# Mersenne numbers represented by a Quadratic polynomial in two variables

Tags: nt.number-theory

Every Mersenne number of index $n >2$

`$$
M_n = 2^n-1
$$`

is represented by the quadratic polynomial 
$$
Q(x,y) = 28x^2+4y^2+28x+4y+7
$$

e.g.,

`$$
M_3=Q(0,0), M_4=Q(0,1), M_5=Q(0,2),M_6=Q(1,0),
$$
$$
M_7=Q(0,5),M_8=Q(2,4),M_9=Q(3,6),M_{10}=Q(1,15).
$$`

Since it is believed that there are an infinity of Mersenne primes, this polynomial should
represent an infinity of prime numbers.

Question: It is true that this polynomial represents an infinity of prime numbers ?
(Probably unrelated with Mersenne primes).

Comment: Why not phrase it as "are there infinitely many primes of the form $7x^2+y^2-1$"?

Comment: You are right, is exactly the same thing.

Comment: with $x$ and $y$ both odd ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this was proved by Iwaniec (for any quadratic in two variables satisfying the obvious necessary conditions).

Comment: This was also mentioned here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55384/primes-represented-by-two-variable-quadratic-polynomials

Comment: Let's vote to close as a duplicate, then.

Comment: Nice reference Felipe. I was not aware of that. I repeat here the reference in the link:

Iwaniec, H (1974). Primes represented by quadratic polynomials in two variables. Acta Arithmetica 24, pp. 435-459.