# The Linnik problem for dimension $2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, sums-of-squares

For $N$ an integer, let
$$\Omega_N:=\left\{\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}|\alpha \in\textbf{Z}^n~\text{and}~\|\alpha\|^2=N\right\}.$$
For $n=3$, Linnik asked if the set $\Omega_N$ was uniformly distributed with respect to the normalised Lebesgue's mesure on the sphere as $N$ goes to infinity. In fact this is true if $N$ goes to infinity and affords values for which $\Omega_N$ is empty.

For $n=4$ the result is also true when the limit is taken such as the odd part of $N$ goes to infinity.

For $n=5$ this result is unconditionaly true.

Unfortunatly I can't find any references for the case $n=2$, and it doesn't seem trivial to me. I am asking whether the set 
$$\Omega_N:=\left\{\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}|\alpha \in\textbf{Z}^2~\text{and}~\|\alpha\|^2=x_1^2+x_2^2=N\right\}$$
is uniformly distributed with respect to the Lebesgue's mesure on $\textbf{S}^1$. I can guess that it will not be true for all $N$ thanks to the formula
$$|\Omega_N|=4\sum_{\substack{d|N \\ d~\text{odd}}}{(-1)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}}. $$

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: One problem is that if $N=1 \pmod 4$ is prime, then $|\Omega_N|$ is bounded for all $N$, so obviously it is impossible for points to equidistribute.

Comment: Right, as @MattYoung notes, the nature of the issue is different for $n=2$, and we cannot expect equidistribution. An even more extreme situation is when $N=1 \mod 4$ is prime, so there are exactly $4$ points on the circle of radius $\sqrt N$, and certainly cannot be equidistributed.

Comment: Have you looked at 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159863/angular-equidistribution-of-lattice-points-on-circles ?

Comment: Thank you my friend Don! Nice link... Ok so this isn't a trivial question