# Relation between $\pi$, area and the sides of Pythagorean triangles whose hypotenuse is a prime number

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

Consider all Pythagorean triangles $a^2 + b^2 = p^2$ in which the hypotenuse $p$ is a prime number. Let $h(x) = \sum_{p \le x}p^2$, $a(x) = \sum_{p \le x}ab$ and $r(x) = \sum_{p \le x}(a+b)^2$. Is it true that:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{h(x)}{r(x)} = \frac{\pi}{2+\pi}
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{a(x)}{r(x)} = \frac{1}{2+\pi}
$$

Comment: you might want to give some evidence for these limits.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker You are right. There was a typpo in the second limit. Corrected it. Here is the motivation for these two limits. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348448/a-mysterious-connection-between-primes-and-pi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q:** Is $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{h(x)}{r(x)} = \frac{\pi}{2+\pi} $ ?
**A:** use that $r(x)=h(x)+2a(x)$, hence
$$\frac{h(x)}{r(x)} = \frac{h(x)/a(x)}{2+h(x)/a(x)}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{h(x)}{a(x)}=\pi$$
in view of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3481801/87355