# Conjectures for primes $p\equiv1\pmod3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, binary-quadratic-forms

Let $p$ be a prime with $p\equiv1\pmod3$. It is well known that we can write $p$ uniquely as $a_p^2+a_pb_p+b_p^2$ with $a_p,b_p\in\mathbb Z$ and $a_p>b_p>0$.
Note that $a_b\not \equiv b_p\pmod3$. Thus $p$ can be written uniquely as $c_p^2+c_pd_p+d_p^2$ with $c_p,d_p\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $c_p-d_p\equiv1\pmod3$.

Motivated by [Question 348562 on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/348562), via computation I have formulated the following conjectures concerning primes $p\equiv1\pmod3$.

**Conjecture 1.** We have
$$\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}\left(\frac{a_p-b_p}3\right)=O(\sqrt N)\ \ \quad \text{for}\ N\ge1,$$
where $(-)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

**Conjecture 2.** 
$$\frac{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}c_p}{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}d_p}=1+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt N}\right)\quad\text{for}\ N\ge7.$$

**Conjecture 3.** 
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\frac{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}c_p}{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}b_p}=1+\frac{\sqrt3}2.$$

It is well known that any prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$ can be written uniquely as $x_p^2+y_p^2$ with $x_p,y_p\in\mathbb Z$ and $x_p>y_p>0$.
Also, $p$ can be written uniquely as $u_p^2+v_p^2$ with $u_p,v_p\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $u_p-v_p\equiv1\pmod4$. For primes $p\equiv1\pmod4$, I also have conjectures similar to Conjectures 1-3 for primes $p\equiv1\pmod3$.

**Conjecture 4.** We have
$$\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod4}\left(\frac{-1}{x_p-y_p}\right)=O(\sqrt N)\ \ \quad \text{for}\ N\ge1,$$
where $(-)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

**Conjecture 5.** For any $\varepsilon>0$, we have
$$\frac{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod4}u_p}{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod4}v_p}=1+O(N^{-1/2+\varepsilon})\quad\text{for}\ N\ge5.$$

**Conjecture 6.** 
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\frac{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod4}u_p}{\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod4}y_p}=1+\frac{\sqrt2}2.$$

**QUESTION.** How to solve the above conjectures?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: I have two comments. (1) Is there an over-arching purpose to any of the conjectures? For example, why would we want to think about the Legendre symbols $(\frac{a_p - b_p}{3})$ or $(\frac{-1}{x_p-y_p})$? (2) How much numerical work has been done, e.g., what is the evidence for the limit in Conjecture 3 being $1 + \sqrt{3}/2$ or for Conjecture 5 to have an $\varepsilon$ in it?

Comment: The 6 conjectures are based on my computation for $N=10^6,10^7,10^8,10^9$. I did not mention my checking data in details because I did not want the post too long.

Comment: For example, $(\sum_{p\le10^9\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}c_p)/(\sum_{p\le10^9\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}b_p)\approx 1.86590085$ while $1+\sqrt3/2\approx 1.8660254$.

Comment: My 2012 conjecture that $\lim_{N\to\infty}(\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}a_p)/(\sum_{p\le N\atop p\equiv1\pmod3}b_p) = 1+\sqrt3$ was confirmed by C. Elsholtz and G. Harman in a paper published in 2015.

Comment: People here may doubt my intuition, if many of you don't like this posting I may remove it.