# 'Small' and 'large' discriminants of two-variable quadratic polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory

Chapter 21.2 of Friedlander and Iwaniec's *Opera de Cribro* begins (essentially) as follows:

Let
$$F(X, Y) = aX^2 + bXY + cY^2 + \alpha X + \beta Y + \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}[X, Y]$$ be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X, Y]$, represent arbitrarily large odd integers, and satisfy $(a, b, c, \alpha, \beta, \gamma) = 1$. We want $F(X, Y)$ to depend essentially on two variables, which may be expressed by the requirement that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}$ are linearly independent.

We introduce two discriminants:
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4 ac,$$
$$D = a \beta^2 - b \alpha \beta + c \alpha^2 + \Delta \gamma.$$

[end of excerpt]

Wait, they do what?

F+I go on to state that any $F(X, Y)$ satisfying the above conditions represents infinitely many primes: on the order of $\frac{x}{\log x}$ primes $\leq x$ if $D = 0$ or $\Delta$ is a square, and on the order of $\frac{x}{(\log x)^{3/2}}$ otherwise.

They say only a very little bit about their proof, referring instead to [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa24/aa2451.pdf) paper of Iwaniec. Obviously these discriminants are important (Iwaniec calls them the "small" and "large" discriminants respectively), but Iwaniec does not explain them in any highbrow fashion; he simply dives into the guts of some computations. Predictably, they are related to affine changes of coordinates (we want to say that $F, F'$ are equivalent if an invertible such transformation changes one into the other), but if the role of $D$ is something simple then this wasn't apparent from a quick look at the paper.

Are these two discriminants classical and familiar? Is there a simple highbrow explanation of what they say about the polynomial $F$? It seems there must be.

(See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55384/primes-represented-by-two-variable-quadratic-polynomials) for a related MO question.)

Thank you!

Comment: If you homogenize F, you get a ternary quadratic forms. These were studied by Gauss in his Disquisitiones. There must be a lot on these objects in any book on classical invariant theory (you might want to look at the recent book by Olver with this title).

Comment: @Franz: Qiaochu answered my question (the answer turned out to be quite simple), but this book looks quite interesting and I plan to order it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some naive comments. If $X, Y$ are large then the contribution of the quadratic terms swamps the other terms, so first let's concentrate on the quadratic terms
$$Q(X, Y) = a X^2 + b XY + c Y^2.$$

This can be written as
$$Q(X, Y) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} X & Y \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & \frac{b}{2} \\\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\\ Y \end{array} \right]$$

and the matrix occurring above has determinant $ac - \frac{b^2}{4} = - \frac{\Delta}{4}$. $Q$ is positive-definite if and only if $\Delta < 0$, in which case this determinant has concrete geometric significance: it is $\pi$ times the reciprocal of the area of the ellipse $Q(X, Y) \le 1$. Consequently it describes the asymptotics of the number $q_n$ of pairs of integers $(X, Y)$ such that $Q(X, Y) \le n$ (and the same should be true of $F$). In all cases, $\Delta$ is invariant under affine change of coordinates.

$F$ itself can be written as

$$F(X, Y) = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} X & Y & 1 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a & \frac{b}{2} & \frac{\alpha}{2} \\\
 \frac{b}{2} & c & \frac{\beta}{2} \\\
 \frac{\alpha}{2} & \frac{\beta}{2} & \gamma \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\\ Y \\\ 1 \end{array} \right]$$

and $D$ is $4$ times the determinant of this matrix. Again this is invariant under affine change of coordinates. $D$ is a natural invariant of the homogenization of $F$ to a ternary quadratic form.

---

Let me also say some naive things about the two conditions appearing in the OP. By the quadratic formula, the quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ has roots
$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}.$$

Consequently, $\Delta$ is a square if and only if this polynomial has rational roots, hence if and only if $Q$ splits into a product of factors 
$$Q(X, Y) = (dX + eY)(fX + gY)$$

over $\mathbb{Z}$ (by Gauss' lemma). As Will Jagy says, these quadratic forms have very different behavior as far as representing primes compared to quadratic forms that do not factor this way.

If $\Delta$ is not a square, then it is in particular not zero. Now, if $D = 0$, then the $3 \times 3$ matrix above has nontrivial nullspace. I believe this is equivalent to being able to write $F$ as the product of two linear polynomials (after a suitable quadratic extension) as opposed to the product of two linear polynomials plus a constant.

Comment: "$D$ is 4 times the determinant of this matrix": aagh, somehow missed that. There's the simple explanation! +1, sir.

Answer (score 6):

I made two corrections in your formula for $D.$ It is now consistent with the 1974 Acta Arithmetica paper.

Some examples. If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are all $0,$ we have a quadratic form, which is required primitive. For positive forms, the proportion of primes represented is a constant times the full count of primes, this is Cebotarev density. See Theorem 9.12 on page 188 of David A. Cox, *Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$*

In comparison, $X^2 + Y^2 + 1$ represents a constant times $\frac{x}{( \log x )^{3/2}}$ primes up to $x.$ I was not aware of this. Note that this case was proved by [IWANIEC 1972](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/mathbwn/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-aav21i1p203bwm?q=e38d3128-78b9-4500-a8fc-cae82bd63b64%241&qt=IN_PAGE) where the pdf can be downloaded. He does this special case and improves on estimates of Motohashi.

My understanding is that, for nondegenerate indefinite quadratic forms, that is $aX^2 + b XY + c Y^2$ with $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c$ nonnegative but not zero or a square, the number of primes $p$ represented and the number of primes $q$ such that $-q$ is represented both obey a Cebotarev-like law. Franz would know details. I am taking primes as positive only. For example, $X^2 - 3 Y^2$ represents all (positive) primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12},$ and all $-q$ for positive primes $q \equiv 11 \pmod {12}.$

If, instead, I take a degenerate indefinite form as $X^2 - Y^2,$ I can represent all multiples of $4$ and all odd numbers. So the number of primes up to some positive bound $x$
is just the usual $\frac{x}{\log x}$ from the Prime Number Theorem, without any constant multiplier.

Finally, what happens with $X^2 + Y^2 + 2 X + 1$ or $X^2 - Y^2 + 2 X + 1?$ These can be rewritten with $(X+1)^2 = X^2 + 2 X + 1.$

So, overall, they are saying that two distinct cases give PNT times a constant, either degenerate (representing an entire arithmetic progression containing more than one prime) or a genuine nondegenerate quadratic form, which does not represent any arithmetic progression but may represent all primes in an arithmetic progression (such as $X^2 + Y^2$ and $4n+1,$ which behavior requires very small class number) but in any case follows a Cebotarev-like rule for primes.

As an example without arithmetic progressions, $x^2 + xy + 6 y^2$ and $2x^2 \pm xy + 3 y^2.$ Both represent only primes $23$ and $p$ that satisfy $(p|23) = 1.$ The first represents those for which $z^3 - z + 1$ has a root $\pmod p,$ accounting for $1/6$ of all primes in the long run, the latter pair of forms (both) represent the others, accounting for $1/3$ of all primes.  Oh, $23$ itself is represented by the first one.

The other case is like $X^2 + Y^2 + 1,$ representing fewer primes but still infinite.

So, they have managed to put together a number of different cases with two constants.